# discerning between "to" and" in"

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

A. ***In*** creating a description, the writer must identify the important characteristics of...

B. ***To*** create a description, the writer must identify the important characteristics of...

It would be appreciated, if someone please show me if they would mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first read, they both seem to mean that writers must identify and include important characteristics in their descriptions. These adverbs could be used as well:

> **When** creating a description...
>   **While** creating a description...

In this context, if I were to paraphrase what you've written, the *in creating* version seems to mean:

> While a writer is in the process of creating a description, the writer must...

while the *to create* version means:

> As part of the process of creating a description, the writer must...

So, perhaps they don't mean exactly the same thing, but, in this context, they are two sides of the same coin, and the same meaningful information is conveyed.

I'm trying to see how this general construct can be used in other contexts. For example, these:

> To create a large splash, jump into the swimming pool [cannonball style](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dD2veFDZh-c/TfVhQDr3O1I/AAAAAAAAAAM/3mdgw08M3-E/s320/Physics.jpg).
>   To create a painting, start with a blank canvas and a palatte.
>   To build a house, start with a firm foundation.
>   To make a moist cake, use baking flour instead of whole wheat flour.
>   To administer CPR, gently tilt the subject's head back to clear the airway.

would map to:

> In creating a large splash, jump into the swimming pool cannonball style.
>   In creating a painting, start with a blank canvas and a palatte.
>   In building a house, start with a firm foundation.
>   In making a moist cake, use baking flour instead of whole wheat flour. 
>   In administering CPR, gently tilt the subject's head back to clear the airway.

In my mind, the ***to «verb»*** versions read much better than the ***in «verbing»*** versions; the latter wordings sound a bit forced and unnatural. It's hard to put my finger on why, but the *to* version seems like a better option to use in the general case.